# WYSIWYG editor TinyMce settings don't work in IE9

Tags: jquery, asp.net, tinymce, wysiwyg

I use TinyMce in my application. It works great. I faced one issue that when user types something in the editor and presses enter, the editor inserts a blank extra line. I prevent this by using `force_p_newlines: false` it works perfectly in Chrome but not in IE9.

Any ideas on what else to write in the init code for editor? I also used `force_br_newlines : false` but it doesn't work either.

Comment: maybe this one help for you http://www.devicemedia.ca/tinymce-vs-internet-explorer-9-ie9-problem-solved/

Comment: No, I don't have such problems described in the article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this to work by doing this. (add these line in the `intit` code for `tinymce`)

```
forced_root_block: false,
force_br_newlines : true,
force_p_newlines: false,
```